# Get android architecture vith bash

Tags: android, bash

How to get processor architecture without dpkg using android command line
with dpkg bash code

```
case `dpkg --print-architecture` in
                aarch64)
                        archurl="arm64" ;;
                arm)
                        archurl="armhf" ;;
                amd64)
                        archurl="amd64" ;;
                x86_64)
                        archurl="amd64" ;;
                i*86)
                        archurl="i386" ;;
                x86)
                        archurl="i386" ;;
                *)
                        echo "unknown architecture"; exit 1 ;;
                esac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/system/bin/sh

case `arch` in
 aarch64)
    archurl="arm64" ;; 
arm)
    archurl="armhf" ;;
amd64) 
    archurl="amd64" ;;
x86_64)
    archurl="amd64" ;;
i*86) 
    archurl="i386" ;;
x86)
    archurl="i386" ;;
*)
    echo "unknown architecture"; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.